# Get variable values android

Tags: java, android

I currently have 2 variables, `iR` and `iL`, which are defined as the number of times that the user touches the screen. I define them as shown below:

```
public class Touchscreen extends Activity {

int iL;
int iR;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_touchscreen);

        final View touchLayoutL = findViewById(R.id.touchLayoutL);
        final View touchLayoutR = findViewById(R.id.touchLayoutR);
        final Button redo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.redo);
        final Button next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);

        iL=1;
        iR=1;

        touchLayoutL.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                if (event.getAction()==(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)){
                    iL++;
                }
        });

        touchLayoutR.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                if (event.getAction()==(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)){
                    iR++;
                }
        });

        if (iL>1 || iR>1) redo.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        if (iL>3 && iR>3) next.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    }
```

What I'm having trouble with is the last two lines of code,

```
        if (iL>1 || iR>1) redo.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        if (iL>3 && iR>3) next.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

for some reason, the `Typeface` of `redo` and `next` never change. I have tried moving these two lines in different places, but they still do not work. Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `for some reason` reason being that your method is executed before the user touches the screen.

Comment: @user3616949 You are providing a null Typeface, with a bold flag.  You should be doing `redo.setTypeface(redo.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD)`.

Answer (score 3):

That's because

```
    if (iL>1 || iR>1) redo.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    if (iL>3 && iR>3) next.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

is only executed in the onCreateMethd, but not attached to the listeners.

Try moving into the onTouch methods

Answer (score 0):

The `setTypeface` requires a `Typeface`, you cannot use `null`.

If you want to use whatever the current `Typeface` is of the `Button` you can use the [TextView#getTypeface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTypeface%28%29) method.

```
if (iL>1 || iR>1) redo.setTypeface(redo.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
if (iL>3 && iR>3) next.setTypeface(next.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

Or, if you are using the `normal` font then you can use the `setTypeface` single-paramter method.  In which case you would provide `Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD`

```
if (iL>1 || iR>1) redo.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
if (iL>3 && iR>3) next.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

/*
 * Same as above

if (iL>1 || iR>1) redo.setTypeface(Typeface.NORMAL, Typeface.BOLD);
if (iL>3 && iR>3) next.setTypeface(Typeface.NORMAL, Typeface.BOLD);

 */
```